# Where is this DHCP reply coming from?

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

I'm using a ZTE F609 FTTH consumer gateway device **as a switch and AP only**, because my old LinkPro 4-port mini switch died. I only plug cables into the LAN ports, disabled DHCP (which was originally set to the 192.168.1.x subnet). It's connected to my main gateway (a ZTE F660) which has the IP 192.168.6.1. The F609 I give an IP of 192.168.6.254 so I can manage it too.

Now the problem is whenever I connect a device to the F609 (both using Wifi and ethernet) in DHCP IP mode, it always gets a weird IP starting with 10.250.x.x, with the DHCP server showing as 10.250.0.1. I can ping that IP, but no internet connection. So this is a problem because I have to set static IP on every device if I want it to connect through the F609. Where is this IP coming from?

[here is a network diagram to help explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbnBU.png)

Comment: Never try using a router as a switch - They never behave as intended.

Comment: @johnnyvegas disagree. While its not great from a speed POV as a switch  there is nothing intrinsically wrong with disabling DHCP and using the lan ports if a router as a switch. Using it as ab AP is fairly common and can work well.

Comment: Since you've been able to ping it, you should have an arp entry for 10.250.0.1. Look up the entry and check the MAC address against the OUI lookup tool (https://www.wireshark.org/tools/oui-lookup.html). That'll at least give you an indication of what the device is.

Comment: @davidgo For the sake of one of the cheapest networking components available the trouble simply isn't worth it. Causes more problems than it will ever solve.